# ReactJS: e.preventDefault() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple todo app, where i have put in the logic to edit and delete the todos as well. I'm trying to update the parent state from child component but when i'm trying to click on delete it is throwing me an error e.preventDefault() is not a function and it is removing all of the todos here are the components:

PARENT

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       listArr: [],
    }

  }


 deleteTodos(i) {
   var lists = this.state.listArr;
   lists.splice(i, 1);
   this.setState({listArr: lists})
 }

render() {
 .......
 <ToDoList {...this.state} passDeleteTodos={this.deleteTodos} />
......

}
```

CHILD

```
export class ToDoList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              editing: false,
            };

        handleDelete(e, i) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.passDeleteTodos()
        }


    renderDisplay() {
        return(
          <div>
           {
            this.props.listArr.map((list,i) => {
               return(
                 <div key={i} index={i} ref="text">
                  <li>{list}
                    <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
                     <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                             onClick={() => this.handleDelete(i)}
                     />
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass the event object to `handleDelete` function  when you make use of Arrow function as done in your implementation.

You can think of an arrow function like a function that calls another function to which you need to pass the arguments. Event object is a parameter to the arrow function and you indeed need to pass this on to the `handleDelete` function

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleDelete(e, i)}
```

However after this change you still need to bind the `deleteTodos` function in the parent, since the context of `this` inside this function won't be that of the React class component, you can do it like

```
deleteTodos = (i) =>  {
   var lists = this.state.listArr;
   lists.splice(i, 1);
   this.setState({listArr: lists})
 }
```

or

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       listArr: [],
    }
    this.deleteTodos = this.deleteTodos.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: that is becaue you need to bind `deleteTodos` function in the parent

Comment: Yeah it worked so passing event object as an argument applies only if making use of Arrow function right ?

Comment: As I described in my answer, think of arrow function as a function calling another function and hence you need to pass the argument, however in case of bind, it returns a new function that is binded with the context and the parameters that you pass along with the default paramters

Comment: Ohhh i understood now thanks Shubham you were really helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

I change `e.preventDefault() => e.preventDefault` and `bind` the function.

Example

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
    listArr: [],
   }

  this.deleteTodos = this.deleteTodos.bind(this)

  }
  handleDelete(e, i) {
        e.preventDefault;
        this.props.passDeleteTodos()
        ...
    }

   render() {
    return(
      <div>
       {
        this.props.listArr.map((list,i) => {
           return(
             <div key={i} index={i} ref="text">
              <li>{list}
                <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
                 <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
                         onClick={(e,i) => this.handleDelete(e,i)}
                 />
                </div>
            </div>
       )}
      }
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending `e` to the correspondent method.

You could also `bind` the event
`onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, i)}`

Same applies for `deleteTodos` in the `App` component.

Either way you can use the same approach or bind it in the constructor:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       listArr: [],
    }

    this.deleteTodos = this.deleteTodos.bind(this)
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doesn't behave the same way as an  so you can't expect the same preventDefault call.

But your problem is you in bind the order of params change. So you're binded param becomes first in the function. See my snippet below.

```js
const App = () => {
  const _click = (externalVar, e) => {
    console.log("PARAMS", externalVar, e);
  };
  
  const externalVar = 1
  
  return (
    <button onClick={_click.bind(undefined, externalVar)}>click me</button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Like it says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

> arg1, arg2, ... Arguments to **prepend** to arguments provided to the
>   bound function when invoking the target function.

Answer (score 0):

arrow function in react doesn't need to bind to this.
But during call to the functions, for example to call this function handleDelete

```
 handleDelete(e, i) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.passDeleteTodos()
    }
```

we will use synatx as:

```
handleDelete.bind(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleDelete(e, i) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.passDeleteTodos()
    ...
}

onClick={(e,i) => this.handleDelete(e,i)}
```

if the above code is not working properly try this.

```
handleDelete(i) {
    this.props.passDeleteTodos()
    ...
}

onClick={(e,i) => {e.preventDefault(); this.handleDelete(i)}}
```

Comment: Your first example is incomplete because when the handleDelete function is being called, it's not receiving the `e` arg.

Comment: code updated, first, one is not worked for me either, but the second one worked