# e.preventDefault() is not a function in Reactjs, bind used

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, i want to pass an a value as an argument when the user clicks, and also preventDefault, i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507715/reactjs-e-preventdefault-is-not-a-function) that suggest using bind i used it as the code below but didnt solve my problem, it gave me the error `TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function`.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      headline:'',
      articles:[],
      article:[],
    }
  }


componentDidMount(){
  axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/news")
  .then(res=>{this.setState({articles:res.data})}
  )
}




browse = (e,id) => {
  console.log(e)
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(id)
  axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/news/"+id)
  .then(res=>{this.setState({article:res.data,});console.log(res.data)})
}
```

```
Here's where i use the browse method

  {this.state.articles.map(art=> {return (
                     <tr>
                    <td><a href={art.url}>{art.headline}</a></td>
                    <td>{art.topic}</td>
                    <td>{art.author}</td>
                    <td><button  onClick ={this.browse.bind(this,art._id.$oid)} > Browse </button></td>
                                            </tr>
                                      )})}
```

Here's the error

```
×
TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
App.browse
src/App.js:36
  33 |         }
  34 | 
  35 | browse = (e,id) => {
> 36 |   e.preventDefault()
  37 |   axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/news/"+id)
  38 |   .then(res=>{this.setState({article:res.data,});console.log(res.data)})
  39 | }
View compiled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, by writing onClick in that way, you are calling the function as the component is rendered and the passed "e" is not the event, so e.preventDefault() is not a function.

For binding onClick without calling it at the runtime and passing "event" you can use the following format as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers):

```
onClick={(e) => this.browse(e, id)}
```

Comment: with this is not telling preventDefault is not exist, but still reload the page.

Comment: please test putting the line "e.preventDefault()" at first before the "console.log(e)" and let me know about the result

Comment: still reload, here's the code https://gist.github.com/sadakmed/891ef036e67a290c9fd3fcbb3d588eb1

Comment: why are you calling the "this.componentDidMount();" again? everything seems to be working fine for me

Comment: i just added it, because when it reloads. it gives an error of the this.state.articles that is not there. can i do this other way?